# VPN blocks almost everything in command and gnome

Tags: gnome, vpn, openvpn

I am using an ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with Linux 5.3.0-46 generic kernel.

When I am not on the corporate vpn, I can use my computer freely without any delays or blocks. My problem is that in the last few weeks (mostly during pandemic), if I log on to the corporate VPN (via openvpn), I get sluggish behavior on Gnome (gnome apps, like loading any terminal, trying to run vnc viewer etc) or even loading new tabs on opened terminals.

I get the same problem when trying to run commands in the command prompt. I do get that this is something that a company policy might have applied, but is there a way to find out what processes cause this, so that I would give the IT department proof that it needs fixing?

Comment: You might have to be more specific on what "sluggish behaviour" means. To start with, use Task Manager to see if something is causing high CPU load, or iotop for high disk access load.

Comment: Sluggish -- for example I try to run gnome terminal and it fails to run 2 out of 5 times then at a latter time those are being executed. This doesn't happen outside VPN. Also nautilus. My hunch says that there is a watchdog process and does not allow multiple instances of the application or so. Again, due to having this regulated by the IT department, I am running in the dark here as well.

Comment: OpenVPN should not cause that kind of behaviour, unless your company made you install something else on your machine. Again, try to find out if there are processes with high CPU or memory load using Task Manager or top when that happens, and if the processes you launch appear in the task list or not. To get a quick overview if something fishy is going on on your system I recommend a system monitor like gkrellm or conky, which shows you CPU, disk, memory and network load at a glance. Then if something seems suspicious you can investigate further using tools like top, iotop or nethogs.